# how to show error message if route not found in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

If I change route name from url then how can I show the error message in larvel 5.2.
Suppose I am showing users list using url lara.local.com/users and I change the route like lara.local.com/userswwwww. In that case how to show error message.

Answer (score 5):

It will throw 404 Not Found. To display a custom view while a URL not found create a file named `404.blade.php` in your `resources/views/errors/` directory. Whatever you write on that file it will be displayed. No need to do anything else. Laravel will handle the rest.

Comment: definitely a nice way to take advantage of laravel.  Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can use exception handler for handle route not found errors. Update `app\Exception\Handler.php` like

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
    }

    if ($this->isHttpException($e))
    {
        if($e->getStatusCode()===404 || $e->getStatusCode()===405)
        {
            return response()->view('errors.not-found', [], 404);
        }
        return $this->renderHttpException($e);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```